# Perl removing the files using system command returns success always

Tags: perl

I have a script which takes filenames (with its full path) as an arguments and deletes them from the system.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

warn "No arguments/files names passed to the script: $!\n" unless @ARGV;

my $count = 0;

foreach (@ARGV) {
    my $cmd = "rm -rf $_";
    
    my $exit_code = system($cmd); 
    
    if($exit_code != 0){
        print "Command $cmd failed with an exit code of $exit_code.\n";
        exit($exit_code >> 8);
    } else {
        print "Command $cmd successful!\n";
        $count++;
    }
}

print "Out of ".scalar(@ARGV)." file(s) ".$count." file(s) deleted\n";
```

I have two questions:

1. Here if I pass the dummy file say the file which doesn't exists, it gives me `$exit_code` as `0`. How it is possible ? Shouldn't it through exit code other than `0` ?
2. When I delete the file in Perl way `unlink $_;` it doesn't delete them. How can I forcefully delete using `unlink` command ?

Comment: exit codes are 0 for a successful system call. perls `unlink` will delete files as long as you have permission to delete them. You need to make sure you have the absolute path to the file or the relative path from dir where the script is being called as well.

Comment: rm -f :ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt. This is why rm returns 0, you are using the -f option. You can instead check if the file exists before removing it

Comment: @BryanK actually the user which creates the files is deleting these files with absolute path. I believe here I won't be getting any permission issue. But question is why `unlink` doesn't work as `rm` ?

Comment: `unlink` certainly deletes files. If it does not, it is because of file permissions or locks, then you can check the return code of `unlink`. Show the code used for the unsuccessful `unlink` attempt.

Comment: @TLP Can `unlink` forcefully delete the files?

Comment: There are lots of reasons a file will not delete. If it has been set to immutable, the sticky bit is set on the directory containing the files (and you are not the owner of the files) or simply the user running your script does not have write permissions of the files. The point is none of that has to do with `unlink`. You have to have proper permissions before removing a file using any method at all whether its `rm` or `unlink` etc.

Comment: Please be aware that `unlink` can only remove files and it will fail if you pass a directory as an argument.

Comment: @vkk05 It deletes files. What you mean by "forcefully" is another question. It will not exceed what the system allows.

Comment: `my $cmd = "rm -rf $_"; my $exit_code = system($cmd);` dangerously suffers from a [code injection bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)! You want `system("rm", "-rf", "--", $_)`

Answer (score 1):

> Here if I pass the dummy file say the file which doesn't exists, it
> gives me $exit_code as 0. How it is possible ? Shouldn't it through
> exit code other than 0 ?

You are using rm with the -f option. From the man page of rm:

```
-f, --force
              ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

With this option, as far as I know, you will always get a return code of `0` when trying to remove a file that does not exist.

> When I delete the file in Perl way unlink $_; it doesn't delete them.
> How can I forcefully delete using unlink command ?

There are lots of reasons a file will not delete. If it has been set to immutable, the sticky bit is set on the directory containing the files (and you are not the owner of the files) or simply the user running your script does not have write permissions of the files. The point is none of that has to do with unlink. You have to have proper permissions before removing a file using any method at all whether its rm or unlink etc.

Comment: Re "*or simply the user running your script does not have write permissions of the files*", You don't need write permission to the file to delete it; you need write permission to the directory in which it resides. At least on unix systems. (`unlink` already works as if `-f` had been used, since `-f` bypasses a self-imposed limitation of `rm`.)

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `rmtree` from [File::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path). No need to shell out at all to get a recursive delete.

As [BryanK already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65039671/2766176), `0` is the expected error code with the `-f` options. When you run into these issues, test the command in the shell to see if it's Perl (or whatever), or the command. The exit value of the command shows up in `$?` (the shell version, which is why Perl's variable has the same name):

```
$ rm -rf test_dir
$ echo $?
0
```